# How to separate multiple commands passed to eval in bash

Tags: bash, shell, eval

I'm trying to evaluate multiple lines of shell commands using `eval`, but when I try to resolve variables with eval separated by a newline `\n` the variables are not resolved.

```
x='echo a'
y='echo b'
z="$x\n$y"
eval $x
eval $y
eval $z
```

Which outputs:

```
a
b
anecho b
```

The last command gives `anecho b`, and apparently `\n` was treated as `n` there. So is there a way to evaluate multiple lines of commands (say, separated by `\n`)?

Comment: Try separating with `;`, not `\n`

Comment: or with `&&`, if you want to make sure the later cmd gets exec if the previous ran successfully.

Comment: @Kent `&&` does not work if a previous command is incomplete, e.g. `x='if true'; y='then echo a; fi'`

Comment: @Yihui oh, yes, in that case, `&&` won't work. I thought the commands are complete.  btw, read your homepage. :) ZhuNiHaoYun!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`\n` is not a newline; it's an escape sequence that *in some situations* will be translated into a newline, but you haven't used it in one of those situations. The variable `$z` doesn't wind up containing a newline, just backslash followed by "n". As a result, this is what's actually being executed:

```
$ echo a\necho b
anecho b
```

You can either use a semicolon instead (which requires no translation), or use `\n` in a context where it *will* be translated into a newline:

```
$ newline=$'\n'
$ x='echo a'
$ y='echo b'
$ z="$x$newline$y"
$ eval "$z"
a
b
```

Note the double-quotes around `"$z"` -- they're actually critical here. Without them, bash will word-split the value of `$z`, turning all whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines) into word breaks. If that happens, `eval` will receive the words "echo" "a" "echo" b", effectively turning the newline into a space:

```
$ eval $z
a echo b
```

This is yet another in the long list of cases where it's important to double-quote variable references.

Comment: excellent! thanks for the `$newline` trick and explaining the double quotes

Answer (score 5):

You are passing the newline into eval.  So it's like you are on the console typing this:

```
el@voyager$ echo a\necho b
anecho b
```

So the first `echo` is understood correctly, and it thinks you want quotes around the rest.  The backslash seems to be ignored.  Perhaps you meant something like this:

```
el@voyager$ echo -e 'a\n'; echo b
a

b
```

**Option 1:**

delimit statements passed into eval with a semicolon like this:

```
x='echo a'
y='echo b'
z="$x;$y"
eval $x
eval $y
eval $z
```

prints:

```
a
b
a
b
```

**Option 2:**

Put the newline in the place where it will be interpreted by the echo, like this:

```
x='echo -e "a\n"'
y='echo b'
z="$x;$y"
eval $x
eval $y
eval $z
```

prints:

```
a

b
a

b
```

Now the newline is preserved and interpreted by the echo, not the eval.

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily the optimal way as it will fail if the `x` and `y` variables contain sequences processed by printf like `%s` and similar but anyway, here is a method to do it while keeping `\n` as a separator:

```
x='echo a'
y='echo b'
z="$x\n$y"
eval $x
eval $y
export IFS=" "
eval $(printf "$z")
```

prints:

```
a
b
a
b
```

Answer (score 3):

A slightly different approach:

```sh
read -r -d '' script <<'EOF'
echo a
echo b
EOF

eval "$script"
```

outputs

```
a
b
```

### Explanation

- `read -r -d '' script`

  - `-r` - do not allow backslashes to escape any characters
  - `-d ''` - continue until the first character of DELIM is read, rather than newline (makes it read until EOF)
  - `script` - the name of the variable to save the result in
- `<<'EOF'` - use a heredoc WITHOUT variable expansion (the single quotes around the `EOF` stops the variable expansion)

### Alternative

This could also be done using `$(cat <<'EOF'...EOF)`, but this way does not needlessly use cat and does not use a subshell.

Example with useless cat:

```sh
script=$(cat <<'EOF'
echo a
echo b
EOF
)

eval "$script"
```

Answer (score 0):

On my FreeBSD box, I was trying do something in a Bourne script which at first seemed fairly trivial - but clouded my mind for a few moments. Since this page is what I referred to trying to fix my problem, I will explain what I needed to do and how I got it done :

```
a=A

b=B

eval ${a}_${b}="something"
```

No problems so far. I get a new variable A_B that stores "something"

But if I spread the assignment over 2 lines as under :

```
eval ${a}_${b}="some

thing"
```

The shell barks back at me that it could find no command called 'thing'. It is important to understand that eval tries to evaluate RHS as a command. To get eval to evaluate RHS as a string, you have to double-double quote RHS :

```
eval ${a}_${b}="\"some

thing\""
```

Hope this helps someone.
Manish Jain

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking of using the more powerful zsh instead of bash?
If so, you may want to take advantage of process substitution and heredoc. The following code works similarly to the title.

```
source <(cat << EOF
command1
command2
EOF
)
```